# Issue faced while retrieving the record having null value with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select

I am facing issue to obtain the record of the employee which consists of the null value in some particular columns.

**Scenario:**

I have got the following table:

```
employee_id      Name       job_id      department_id
(int)           (varchar)    (int)        (int)
-------------------------------------------------------
1                Sita         1             4
2                Ram          3             5
3                Hari       (null)        (null)
```

The query to SELECT the employee record is given below:

```
        SELECT 
            employees.EMPLOYEE_ID,
            employees.Name,
            jobs.job_title,
            departments.department_name,
        FROM
            employees,jobs,departments
        WHERE
            jobs.job_id=employees.job_id 
            AND departments.department_id=employees.department_id
```

**Test Done:**

With the above query, I'm able to fetch the records of the employees having employee_id = 1 and employee_id = 2 .

**Problem Faced:**

But with the same query, I'm not able to fetch the record of the employee having employee_id = 3.

**Required Outcome:**

The record of the the employee_id = 3 should be displayed.

What correction do I need to get my desired outcome?

Comment: Just use left join

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't add tags for products not involved.)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

You simply want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID, e.Name, j.job_title, d.department_name,
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON j.job_id = e.job_id LEFT JOIN
     departments d
     ON d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion.